# Mongoid Twitter-style following, can't specify criteria/conditions for relationship array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, mongoid

I'm at my wit's end trying to handle these errors.  Basically, I've created the following User and Relationship patterns, using Mongoid to handle my database.  This seems like a near-carbon copy of the example at the bottom of the page [here](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/).  I'm trying to call any of the following:

```
user1.relationships.find(:all, :conditions => {:rel_user => user_in_question, :rel_type => "following" })
user1.relationships.all(:conditions => {:rel_user => user_in_question, :rel_type => "following" })
user1.relationships.where(:rel_type => "following")
user1.relationships.following #with a named scope
```

These all seem to just return the entire relationships array; they don't search through by criteria.  The find() method also throws an error saying that it only can take 1 argument.  The im_following? method always returns true.

I'm not sure if it's better to post code in-line or from gist, so here are the gists:

[user.rb](https://gist.github.com/7328ff45a3db67595712)
[user_follow_spec.rb](https://gist.github.com/a2ff14712cd74ad8c402)
[relationship.rb](https://gist.github.com/6988ae9a1b50de1108c1)

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rockmanioff, I have also came across the same issue. You might want to look at [this](https://groups.google.com/group/mongoid/browse_thread/thread/9ac74dc9a08a5fe2/4c036768d39bf830) as well. Mongoid plans on supporting this feature on their release candidate version. For now, we have to do things manually.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  references_many :fans, :stored_as => :array, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :fan_of
  references_many :fan_of, :stored_as => :array, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :fans

  def become_fan_of user
    fan_of << user
    self.save

    user.fans << self
    user.save
  end

  def is_a_fan? user
    fan_of_ids.include? user.id
  end

  def unfan user
    fan_of_ids.delete user.id
    self.save

    user.fan_ids.delete self.id
    user.save
  end

  ...
end
```

In console, you can do:

```
User.first.become_fan_of User.last
User.first.is_a_fan? User.last
User.first.unfan User.last
```

In your case you might want to substitute "fan / fan_of" for "followers / following respectively". Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you to simplify your relationships by using self-referential associations. Check out my answer to this question:

[How-to: User has fans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128163/how-to-user-has-fans/4242573#4242573)

I think this is pretty close to the association you want:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  references_many :following, 
                  :class_name => 'User', 
                  :stored_as => :array, 
                  :inverse_of => :followed_by

  references_many :followed_by, 
                  :class_name => 'User', 
                  :stored_as => :array, 
                  :inverse_of => :following
end

# let's say we have users: al, ed, sports_star, movie_star    
sports_star.followed_by << al
movie_star.followed_by << al
sports_star.followed_by << ed
movie_star.followed_by << ed

movie_star.followed_by  # => al, ed
al.following            # => sports_star, movie_star
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class User

  # follows and followers
  references_many :follows, :stored_as => :array , :inverse_of => :followers ,:class_name=>"User"
  references_many :followers, :stored_as => :array , :inverse_of => :follows ,:class_name=>"User"


  def followers
    followers.map 
  end

end
```