# How-to: User has fans

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I need users to be able to become fans of other users. How should I design/set this up?

I need to be able to view details of user fans.

For example. I have user: Foo. Foo has 3 fans. I'd like to be able to find the names of Foo's fans. As such:

```
foo = User.first
foo.name (returns 'Foo')
foo.fans.first.user.name (should return 'bar', since 'bar' is a fan of 'foo')
```

This is how I have it set up at the moment:

```
User model:
  embeds_many :fans
  references_many :fans

Fan model:
  embedded_in :user, :inverse_of => :fans
  referenced_in :user

In console, I do:
  User.first.fans.create!(:user => User.first)
```

and I get:
  **Mongoid::Errors::InvalidCollection: Access to the collection for Fan is not allowed since it is an embedded document, please access a collection from the root document.** I think the problem is, because the fan model is embedded in the user model which has a self-reference to the user model as well....

Your thoughts will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about a self-referential association:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  references_many :fans, 
                  :class_name => 'User', 
                  :stored_as => :array, 
                  :inverse_of => :fan_of

  references_many :fan_of, 
                  :class_name => 'User', 
                  :stored_as => :array, 
                  :inverse_of => :fans
end

# let's say we have users: al, ed, sports_star, movie_star    
sports_star.fans << al
movie_star.fans << al
sports_star.fans << ed
movie_star.fans << ed

movie_star.fans  # => al, ed
al.fan_of        # => sports_star, movie_star
```

The problem is that you are trying to do relational association using only embedded documents. When you have a `Fan` embedded inside a `User`, you can only access the `Fan` through its parent `User`. You can't do something like `Fan.find(some_id)` because there is no collection of `Fan` records.

Eventually, MongoDB will support virtual collections that will allow you to do this. For now, you have to use relational-type associations. If you want to use embedded documents in this case, you have to create some ugly and inefficient custom methods to search through parent records.

With MongoDB and Mongoid, I have found that you can switch between embedded and relational associations easily. SQL-type relationships and embedded relationships both have their place and can be used together to great effect.

Comment: User.first.fans << User.last returns Mongo::OperationFailure: invalid query

Comment: You can't use `first` and `last` like that, and you can't modify associations in place like that. Often, `User.last` will return the same thing as `User.first` ! You need to do `u = User.all.entries.first; u2 = User.all.entries.last; u.fans << u2` . I just tested this code out again and it works for me.

Comment: And this will allow me to have users become a fan of themselves as well?

Comment: Yes a user can be a fan of themselves. I just tried a basic example  and it worked: `u = User.create; u.fans << u; u.fans #=> [u]; u.fan_of.entries #=> [u]`

Comment: I dont really understand how this works though. Where is the data for fans being stored? I am doing u = User.all.entries.first; u2 = User.all.entries.last; u.fans << u2; User.first does not show any indication fans in the user. I am also using MongoHub as a GUI tool and dont see Fans anywhere in the User object.

Comment: Moreover, I understand that Mongoid is coming up with a release candidate which will have references_and_referenced_in_many which should support this cause ( https://groups.google.com/group/mongoid/browse_thread/thread/9ac74dc9a08a5fe2/a23544483732df97 ). I am assuming that this is a temporary workaround in the meantime?

Comment: The `fans`are stored as an array of `fan_ids` inside the document. Try `u.fan_ids` . This is how `references_many` works in even the simplest case. All we are doing here that is setting a custom name for the association (`fans` instead of `users`) and linking back to the same model. In the end, we are just storing 2 arrays of ID's in each User: `fan_ids` and `fan_of_ids`. 
I don't know how exactly `references_and_referenced_in_many` will work, but I assume it will implement something very similar to this answer, but make it a lot simpler to declare.

Comment: Hi Bowsersenior, thanks for the suggestion. Based in reference to your example above and the suggestions at https://groups.google.com/group/mongoid/browse_thread/thread/9ac74dc9a08a5fe2/4c036768d39bf830 I have managed to get this working